# Reuse/Inherit from class with main method

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write few different components as separate Console Apps. Each one will have pretty much the same Program.cs class with some configuration inside and of course main method.

I created class library project, there I implemented CommonProgram.cs file with all that stuff including main method.

Now I would like to use it in each one component by simply adding Program.cs classes which would inherit from my CommonProgram.cs class but it's impossible (cant inherit from static class and if I change my CommonProgram.cs class to non static then I cant have Program.cs class in my components static.

What would be the best approach to achieve sth like I just said? Maybe I should just run CommonProgram.cs Main method from Program.cs main method?

Thank you very much for help

Comment: Perhaps you should re-think your architecture. Why not have a single console application which loads all of these modules and passes that same configuration to all of them?

Comment: My suggestion would be to call the Static Method from Program.cs something like CommonProgram.<StaticMethodName>();

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the previous comment, re-think your design.  Since you know that you can't inherit from static classes, move your logic into a class hierarchy that you *can* inherit from. You can factor your configuration-specific information into the derived classes, or into the base class if it has commonality across your different components.  The result of this should be very small main() methods, which is generally a good thing.